# How do I find the hidden states of a HMM for a non time series data? How does EM Algorithm play a role in HMM?

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch

I am a beginner in machine learning. My project requires me to model user intentions using HMM i.e based on parameters like no.of clicks, time on page, etc I have to model whether the user wants to buy a product or not.

Now I know it is a simple classification that can work with logistic regression but I want to do it with HMM.

Now there are 3 parts to this problem:

1. How do I estimate the hidden states? Is there an algorithm for it?
2. What does an EM algorithm do? How do I interpret its result given in the form of Log Likelihood and Standard deviation and mean?
3. Is there any toolbox that gives me matrices of State Transition Probability, Observation Probability Matrix and Initial State Distribution?

Also, how do Baum Welch, Viterbi and EM differ?

Since I am a beginner and a coder, not a math person kindly explain in layman terms.